# Mysql auto start on freebsd 5.3

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I can't seem to figure out how to have mysql start up when booting up for a server than I am now managing.

```
root@: uname -a
FreeBSD .server1 5.3-RELEASE FreeBSD 5.3-RELEASE #0: Fri Nov  5 04:19:18 UTC 2004    root@harlow.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386
```

The script that starts mysql is here: `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql.server`

In /etc/rc.conf, I have `mysql_enabled="yes"`

Anyone have any ideas of what is missing?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you run `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql.server start` as root?

Comment: Nope. Running that as root works fine and mysql is up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5.3 all /usr/local/etc/rc.d scripts must end in .sh in order to be executed.

See  /etc/rc.d/localpkg

Comment: aha! Good catch! the 5.3 part didn't register and you're 100% right.  Rename the script to end in .sh and it should fire up. (Also take this time to remind your client that 5.x is End-Of-Life and an upgrade wouldn't be unwarranted :-)

Comment: Wonderful. I was thinking it might have been a problem with the script name since it was so different. I'll be able to test the change soon.